# PWA not enable with vite-plugin-pwa on Nuxt

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, progressive-web-apps

I just configured my application with the [VitePWA](https://vite-pwa-org.netlify.app/) module, I added some configuration according to the website [documentation](https://vite-pwa-org.netlify.app/frameworks/nuxt) , I added some icons and added the `<NuxtPwaManifest>` tag in app.vue and when I run `npm run dev` I don't get any error messages but it also doesn't run my PWA in Chrome Browser. did I miss any configuration?

**nuxt.config.ts**

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  devtools: { enabled: false },
  modules: [
    '@nuxt/ui',
    '@vite-pwa/nuxt',

    //masukan module nuxt ui jika ingin menggunakan nuxtui tailwindcss dll sudah otomatis tinggal styling saja di index.vue
  ],
  colorMode:{
    preference:'light',

  },
  pwa:{
    manifest:{
      name:'app test',
      short_name:'app test',
      description:'app yang dibuat untuk pwa',
      lang:'en',
      orientation:'portrait',
      icons:[
        {
          src:'assets/img/android-launchericon-48-48.png',
          sizes:'48*48',
          type:'image/png',
        },
        {
          src:'assets/img/android-launchericon-72-72.png',
          sizes:'72*72',
          type:'image/png',
        },
        {
          src:'assets/img/android-launchericon-96-96.png',
          sizes:'96*96',
          type:'image/png',
        },
        {
          src:'assets/img/android-launchericon-144-144.png',
          sizes:'144*144',
          type:'image/png',
        },
        {
          src:'assets/img/android-launchericon-192-192.png',
          sizes:'192*192',
          type:'image/png',
        },
        {
          src:'assets/img/android-launchericon-512-512.png',
          sizes:'512*512',
          type:'image/png',
        },

      ]
    }
  }
})
```

**app.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <NuxtPwaManifest/>
    <NuxtPage/>
  <div>
</template>
```

im trying help with ChatGPT but i didnt get properly solution

Comment: I changed the image size from 48*48 to 48x48, then I also ran `npm run build` and ran with build mode still I got the error Uncaught (in promise) non-precached-url: non-precached-url :: [{"url ":"/"}] at O.createHandlerBoundToURL (http://localhost:3000/workbox-7cfec069.js:1:13245) at Object.createHandlerBoundToURL (http://localhost:3000/workbox-7cfec069.js:1 :14828) at http://localhost:3000/sw.js:1:1055 at http://localhost:3000/sw.js:1:565

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fixed my code now it works, i forgot to add autoUpdate and use x instead of * for resolution and move them into public folder

```
    pwa:{
    registerType:'autoUpdate',
    manifest:{
      name:'app test',
      short_name:'app test',
      description:'app yang dibuat untuk pwa',
      lang:'en',
      orientation:'portrait',
      icons:[
        {
          src:'android-launchericon-48-48.png',
          sizes:'48x48',
          type:'image/png',
        },
        {
          src:'android-launchericon-72-72.png',
          sizes:'72x72',
          type:'image/png',
        },
        {
          src:'android-launchericon-96-96.png',
          sizes:'96x96',
          type:'image/png',
        },
        {
          src:'android-launchericon-144-144.png',
          sizes:'144x144',
          type:'image/png',
        },
        {
          src:'android-launchericon-192-192.png',
          sizes:'192x192',
          type:'image/png',
        },
        {
          src:'android-launchericon-512-512.png',
          sizes:'512x512',
          type:'image/png',
        },

      ],
    },
  },
```